# Select query based on priority to a certain string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
ID|Expense|Name
1|1000|John
1|1000|Roger
1|1000|Megan
2|500|Sally
2|500|John
3|700|Jen
3|700|Mike
```

I want to group by id and expense but want just a single row. Also, I would like to give preference to John while selecting and any random one row if John is not present. (for id=3 any Jen or Mike is acceptable)

Desired outcome:

```
ID|Expense|Name
1|1000|John
2|500|John
3|700|Jen
```

I tried using `Rank`, but I am not able to differentiate against the ids without John.

Please Help

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "random" one row, do you expect that the output would change each time you run the query (assuming it's a non John group) ?

Comment: I dont mind if it changes or not

Comment: Then check the answer by @vkp below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with `row_number` with prioritization using `case` expression.

```
select id,expense,name
from (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by id order by case when name='John' then 1 else 2 end) as rnum
from tbl t
) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: Looks good!  He wants to group by ID and Expense, shouldn't partition be by Id, expense.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with no extra fields is using the **WITH TIES** clause

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Expense] int,[Name] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,1000,'John')
,(1,1000,'Roger')
,(1,1000,'Megan')
,(2,500,'Sally')
,(2,500,'John')
,(3,700,'Jen')
,(3,700,'Mike')

Select Top 1 with ties * 
 from @YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,Expense Order By NullIf(Name,'John'))
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Expense Name
1   1000    John
2   500     John
3   700     Jen
```